# How to get user's email id of google account?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

I am working on an iPhone app in which I am giving user option to login with his/her google account. Now, I want that user's google email id through JSON or XML. I have searched a lot, but did not satisfactory result.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the oauth autorization with google api at their developers site?
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find something from this link.....
hope this link help you.....
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction
and 
also https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/
:)

write bellow code when you want to get contact....

```
GDataServiceGoogleContact *service = [self contactService];
        GDataServiceTicket *ticket;

        BOOL shouldShowDeleted = TRUE;
        const int kBuncha = 2000;

        NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleContact contactFeedURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];

        GDataQueryContact *query = [GDataQueryContact contactQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
        [query setShouldShowDeleted:shouldShowDeleted];
        [query setMaxResults:kBuncha];

        ticket = [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                                    delegate:self
                           didFinishSelector:@selector(contactsFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

        [self setContactFetchTicket:ticket];
```

bellow method is GmailAPI delegate method...

```
- (GDataServiceGoogleContact *)contactService 
{
    static GDataServiceGoogleContact* service = nil;

    if (!service) {
        service = [[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];

        [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
        [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
    }

    [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:txtEmail.text
                                   password:txtPass.text];

    return service;
}
```

after that you can get contact with bellow code...

```
for (int i = 0; i < [contacts count]; i++) {
        GDataEntryContact *contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:i];
        //        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> elementname contact :%@", [[[contact name] fullName] contentStringValue]);
        NSString *ContactName = [[[contact name] fullName] contentStringValue];
        GDataEmail *email = [[contact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0];
        //        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Contact's email id :%@ contact name :%@", [email address], ContactName);
        NSString *ContactEmail = [email address];
}
```

hope this help you....
:)

Comment: I have gone through this, but did not get it. Frankly, I just messed up in the language.

Comment: but i got all detail from this api but now i post some code about it may this helpfull you ... :)

Comment: Hi Paras can u please help me in using Gdata to get email id of friends from gmail account. Ihave Gone through the google gdata documentation it is very confusing and complex. can u please suggest a good tutorial or some help to solve my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: i think try this one ,step by step try to follow whole description for all api i sure you will get best output which you want https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ :)